# Problems with zoom in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, zooming

So, the problem is: if I have for example StackPanel with some elements and one of this elements transforms with Zoom if overlays the near elements, but I need to slide elements to the sides as much as it needs for comfort zooming..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by "transforms with Zoom", but if you are setting a ScaleTransform on an element's RenderTransform property, then try using the [LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) property instead. LayoutTransform is applied before the layout pass, whereas RenderTransform is applied after the layout pass but before the render pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I jut forgot about this problem :(